# How to show the "Home" folder for SSRS 2008 in SQL Management Studio

Tags: windows, ssrs-2008

I just installed SSRS 2008 on a development server and when I connect to it with SQL Management Studio I do not have all of the items in Object Explorer that I had with our SSRS 2005 installation. For example, we are missing the "Home" folder which lists all the reports. When we browse to our /ReportServer URL we can view and run our reports, so I know they are on the server. Does anyone know if this is a permissions issue or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Microsoft decided to take out the duplicate functionality between SSMS and the Report Manager web pages in SSRS 2008.

Most of the report functionality (uploading rdls, data sources, maintaining security, etc.) has to be done through the web interface now.

Wish I had better news...
Dan